# How to animate alpha channel of sprite color using Animator in code in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, animation

I tried Animator + AnimationClipPlayable, but failed. Sprite disappears completely after 1 second, without animation happening. If I set "1" instead of "0" for final point, then nothing happens.

Code:

```
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    AnimationClipPlayable playable = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(clip);

    gameObject.AddComponent<Animator>();

    AnimationCurve alpha = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 255, 1, 0);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(SpriteRenderer), "m_Color.a", alpha);

    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(playable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color.a accepts a float value in the range from 0 to 1, not from 0 to 255. It is also a reason why you see a sudden disappearance, because it gets to 0 at the end.

The solution is simple, change "255" to "1". Code:

```
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    AnimationClipPlayable playable = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(clip);

    gameObject.AddComponent<Animator>();

    AnimationCurve alpha = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 1, 1, 0);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(SpriteRenderer), "m_Color.a", alpha);

    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(playable);
```